# MySql sum query

Tags: mysql

I need a MySql query to do the following:
Select all the items in a table, group them by a type, order them by count type and also sum all the count.

This is what I've done so far:

```
select type, count(*) as cnt from $tbl_name group by type order by count(*) desc;
```

This only gives me the count for each group. What should I add so that this code will **also** show the total count (sum the counts from every group).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from (
select type as type, 
count(*) as cnt 
from $tbl_name 
group by type WITH ROLLUP) as inner_table
order by cnt desc;
```

Note that the first row will be the rolled up total sum.

[ROLLUP reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html)

Comment: And how do I acces the value?

Comment: Sorry I edited the select cause it threw "incorrect usage of ROLLUP and ORDER BY". With what value do you have problem accessing it?

Comment: This query returns: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE

Comment: @Cristy, there is no T_VARIABLE in this query. I just run it (replaced table name and column name) in my MySQL db and it is just fine.

Comment: Sorry my bad, it works ok, but I still don't know how to get the total sum from it. Can you explain that? I mean, I get the cnt by fetching the result and accessing $row['cnt'] , but how do I get the total sum? (inner_table)

Comment: The total sum is `$row['cnt']` in the row where `$row['type']` is empty. This will be the first row since you've ORDERED BY `cnt DESC`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

select type, SUM(count(*)) as cnt from $tbl_name group by type order by count(*) desc;

Comment: I need to have the cnt I've done before and also a variable showing how many items are in total.

Comment: if you fetch the query into `loop`, you can do it there.

Comment: I don't do it, I only fetch the first 6 rows.